# Add a new close reason for implementation and troubleshooting questions

Tags: support, close-reasons, on-topic-definition

Code troubleshooting and code implementation questions are not in Programmers' site scope.  Although there is an option to migrate such questions to Stack Overflow, the vast majority of them are not of sufficient quality to migrate there.  Thus ensues a long-winded explanation of how we don't accept troubleshooting or implementation questions, but your question is not of sufficient quality to be migrated to Stack Overflow, yada yada.

The close reason ought to be simple enough:

> Question about **writing specific code** (i.e. troubleshooting and implementation) are [off-topic on Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  You might be able to get help on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), but *read their [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) first.*

Comment: related: [Can the number of custom close reasons on Programmers be expanded?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6172/31260) and [close reason (and associated expand the close reason count) request](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6106/31260)

Comment: Might be useful to poke shog to see how often "implementation or debugging" (my frequent comment text) or gnat's "fix-my-code-dump request" comments show up on distinct questions (those are the only two that I know of that are consistently worded).

Comment: Hey, [check it out](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257449/new-10k-tool-question-close-statistics) (cc @MichaelT)

Comment: @Shog9 The raw information is quite nice, though given what I see at [/tools/question-close-stats](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tools/question-close-stats) - [the formatting appears to be a bit off](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vE46O.png).

Comment: @Shog9 while looking at the information, I realized that this was for "custom close reason".  Thats great. However, many, many, many times my "this is an implement or debugging issue" *isn't* a custom close reason because I am out of close votes. For example, http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/285200/ or http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/285040/ when I closed it as unclear and added additional information. I am sure there are many others out there.

Answer (score 3):

**At first glance**, this actually does not appear to be a problem (keep reading!!); I used [this SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/edit/319614) to see what custom close reasons we are using for this; only 24 of these 171 questions have a comment that includes the characters `implementation`, `debug`, or `verflow`.

**However, this is not a complete picture of the story.** Sometimes other things happen to these questions:

1. These questions get deleted. This happens often, and therefore cannot be analyzed using SEDE.
2. These questions are migrated to Stack Overflow, even when they are of low quality. This also happens often. Robert Harvey can probably speak to this better than I can.

   - A famous Jeff Atwood quote comes to mind: [Don't migrate crap!!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82941/please-dont-migrate-low-quality-questions-to-other-sites) Without this custom close reason, we will migrate crap far more often than we ought to.
3. People use less accurate close reasons.

   - Of course, this is fine from the principle of crap getting closed, but...
   - It's not fine from the principle of "educating users exactly why things are happening".

**We need this custom close reason.** These questions are already getting closed and deleted by the community **anyway**; having an extra close reason isn't going to change that. What it will do is organize these questions more appropriately, and **educate future users on how and where to ask questions**.