# Merge and replace custom close reason

Tags: support, status-completed, close-reasons

We've been fairly consistently getting poor quality implementation and debugging questions.  A [previous suggestion](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6106/close-reason-and-associated-expand-the-close-reason-count-request) (related: [1](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6172/can-the-number-of-custom-close-reasons-on-programmers-be-expanded) [2](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7394/add-a-new-close-reason-for-implementation-and-troubleshooting-questions)) to increase the count hasn't been acted upon and the suggestion for us was to merge the close reasons that we have.

The two that are likely the best to merge are the "suggest a project" and "suggest a tool".

The existing tool wording is:

> Questions about **what language, technology, or project one should take up next** are off topic on Programmers, as they can only attract subjective opinions for answers. There are too many individual factors behind the question to create answers that will have lasting value. You may be able to get help in [The Whiteboard](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard), our chat room.

The recommendation one is:

> Questions asking us to **recommend a tool, library or favorite off-site resource** are off-topic for Programmers as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The merged close reason:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a **tool, language, book, library, off site resource (including tutorials and examples), or project to undertake** are off topic on Programmers as they attract only subjective and opinionated answers. There are too many individual factors behind these questions to create answers that will have lasting value to others.

---

New close reason:

> Questions asking for **assistance in writing or debugging existing code** are off topic on Programmers. These questions can be asked on Stack Overflow if they include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I especially like that the new close-reason links to MCVE, and *only* to that. I think that's the best we can do there.