# Why is this question off topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-topic-definition

I've asked a [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/352186/typeof-function-cant-be-called-as-a-function), trying to understand a language specific "anomaly", as it's not within my immediate skillset to answer.

What is the purpose of this forum if not to answer Software Engineering questions?

> Software Engineering Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for professionals, academics, and students working within the systems development life cycle.

My question, even though seeming like a "fix teh codez" question, is well within the bounds of what I perceive this forum to be... or is not? The solution/cause seems routed within the language specification / usage thereof...

I actually **intentionally** asked on here and not StackOverflow thinking it would be off-topic on there, as my want (in terms of answer type) was to have received a conceptual answer as opposed to... heres a code sample to fix, which I was told StackOverflow is for

**EG:**

- I know the code is broken.
- I don't particularly care about a fix.
- I aimed to understand the why...

...which is a concept pertaining to Software Engineering in general? (and not just this instance of "broke" code)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge and replace custom close reason](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7721/merge-and-replace-custom-close-reason)

Comment: I don't see how this question is a duplicate of a feature request to modify the close reasons.

Comment: because it has been closed by the [reason implemented per that request](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7722/31260) @Snowman "Questions asking for assistance in writing or debugging existing code are off topic..."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are implementation and debugging questions off-topic on Software Engineering?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7864/why-are-implementation-and-debugging-questions-off-topic-on-software-engineering)

Comment: You may want to describe the topic of your question in the title. Something like "Why is this question about code debugging off topic?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the Help Center and the close reason state that questions about "explaining, writing or debugging code" are off-topic. You're asking us to explain something about the code or language.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up. Hmm.... so I went through the tour, saw nothing CLEAR enough indicating the purpose of the forum, then assumed (wrongly) that this is a good fit. Before asking, I don't normal go to HELP as.. well, why would I. I don't have the need to just yet, as everything seems normal... Thus wouldn't instinctively go to the help section as an "incase"... 

The small section about whats on topic might be something that would be beneficial to add to the sites tour to reduce overall off topic questions.

Comment: @RohanBüchner I just looked at the tour. The phrase "explaining, writing or debugging code" also appears there, under the "Get answers to practical, detailed questions" header in the list of things to not ask about. But the tour is just an introduction - the detailed information is in the Help Center and Meta. If you already understand the general nature of Stack Exchange, you should be checking out the Help Center rather than the Tour for specific information about a site's rules.